# Generalized reaction rate for elementary process

Tags: kinetic-theory, molecular-dynamics, non-equilibrium

Most textbooks give the reaction rate

$$r = k [\mathrm{R}_1]^{a_1}[\mathrm{R}_2]^{a_2}  \tag{1}$$

for the elementary process $a_1 \mathrm{R}_1 + a_2 \mathrm{R}_2 \rightarrow \mathrm{P}$. However, expression (1) is not valid in the general case: e.g. it is lacking fluctuations, small-size corrections, memory effects, relativistic corrections,...

I have seen some derivations of the rate expression (1) using kinetic theory, Langevin approach, or chemical master equation, but the derivations introduced further approximations: e.g. the kinetic theory approach considered only binary collisions in diluted gases under 'local' thermodynamic equilibrium, the Langeving approach only considered unimolecular reactions, the chemical master equation neglects memory-effects,...

What is the **general** expression for the reaction rate for an elementary process and how can the expression be **derived** from first-principles?